# Firebase REST API 307 temp redirect format

Tags: firebase, http, redirect, firebase-realtime-database

I have embedded system with web socket communication. I can connect via SSL to firebase server and then do HTTP stream request so every time is something changed in DB I get notified. Everything works great but there is one thing mentioned in [Firebase REST API docs](https://firebase.google.com/docs/database/rest/retrieve-data#section-rest-streaming) which worries me. And that is point two:

```
2. Respect HTTP Redirects, in particular HTTP status code 307
```

I am requesting:

```
https://fakeproject-b66a6-default-rtdb.europe-west1.firebasedatabase.app/mySecretKey.json"
```

1. Do you know what will be the form of the `Location` key in the header in case of redirect?

- Will it be just path on the same server?
- Or will it be URL to the deferent one with `http://` or `www.` prefix?

2. Will it contain my `mySecretKey.json` at the end?
3. Is there a possibility to try it out somewhere so I get 307 from firebase?

I need to know this because I have to properly parse it and make second request to redirect location.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The servers for the Firebase Realtime Database REST API used to use 307 codes to redirect you to the correct server. Nowadays, they don't use a 307 as frequently anymore, but it may still occur during an update or when traffic is being moved around.

For an example of what you may get, you can try:

```
curl -v -H "Accept: text/event-stream" "https://s-euw1b-nss-500.europe-west1.firebasedatabase.app/test.json?ns=patryk-newest-rtdb-eu"
```

By passing an `Accept: text/event-stream` header we prevent the proxying that would otherwise happen, so we can see the redirect flow.

The response I'm getting:

```
< HTTP/1.1 307 Temporary Redirect
< Server: nginx
< Date: Fri, 25 Mar 2022 00:18:05 GMT
< Content-Type: text/plain
< Content-Length: 0
< Connection: keep-alive
< Location: https://s-euw1b-nss-200.europe-west1.firebasedatabase.app/test.json?ns=patryk-newest-rtdb-eu&sse=true
< Access-Control-Allow-Origin: *
< Strict-Transport-Security: max-age=31556926; includeSubDomains; preload
```

Comment: Thank you, btw what ns=patryk-newest-rtdb-eu parameter does? I could not find anything.

Comment: It's the lookup instruction that our SDKs do. You're reaching out to a known server (`s-euw1b-nss-200.europe-west1.firebasedatabase.app`), but then asking it to access a specific database instance (`patryk-newest-rtdb-eu`) through that server. If the database is on another server, this proxies the request for regular REST calls, but for text/event-stream it sends a redirect back.

Comment: Okay now everything makes sense to me, thank you for your help ❤